# git : disable auto-merge for a git merge --squash -X theirs

Tags: git, merge, squash

I want the following workflow for my project :

- 2 branches : dev and master (I make it simple for this question, but I actually also use features and release branches)
- I commit technical changes on the dev branch.
- When I want to release a new big version, I merge dev into master but without keeping the dev history.
  I don't want master branch to have any technical message like "Fixed bug in blablabla". I just want my master branch to show me the important release versions like this :

  `Initial commit ----- [PROD V1] ------ [PROD V2] ------`

For that behavior, I use

```
git merge dev --squash -X theirs
```

on master branch to retrieve all changes that have been made in dev branch in the working directory of master, then create one single commit with the `[PROD]` message and push.

The problem is that, after I tried the `merge dev --squash -X theirs` on master branch, I noticed that some few files are baddly auto-merged (some entiere blocks of code are added twice..) which provoke eventually numerous errors in my PHP scripts.

As I understood, -X theirs take "theirs" (dev) version, but only ***when auto merging is not possible***. The problem comes from auto merging (I saw that all files with that problem has been auto-merged).

How can I just disable auto-merging so all the files in the master branch are litterally replaced by the content of dev ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer. git merge is meant to incorporate changes from a version of a file into another version. This is just not a replace tool.

`-X theirs` just auto resolves a conflict by choosing their version, but **at certain very particular lines** (not whole file) where git doesn't know what to do. It's definitely not meant to replace the whole content of a file with "their" version, as I thought.

To replace the content of the file with "their" (dev) version, I did :

```
git merge dev --squash
```

Git says there are not resolved conflicts. Now to **replace** with their version for all files, I did :

```
git checkout --theirs *
```

And finally mark all conflict as resolved :

```
git add -u
```

Commit and push and it's all good :)

Comment: This is correct, though if you only want the `--theirs` to apply to *conflicted* files you won't want a `*` here, and if you want the `--theirs` to apply to *all* files and you're using a Unix-style shell, you'll either need to quote the `*`, or use `.` at the top level of the repository. The latter is usually better because `*` does not match dot-files (well, you can configure whether it does, if you use bash, for instance, but the default is "not").

Comment: Didn't know * doesn't stand for hidden files. I'll check my production server again, thank you for that remark !

Comment: In Git, `*` generally matches dot files, but in shells, it generally doesn't. If you're using library file name match functions, they often take a flag (`FNM_PERIOD` for instance) telling them whether `*` matches, e.g., `.bashrc`. In bash itself, you can set the `dotglob` option.